# 2P circuit breaker, Ground wiring

Tags: ground, circuit-breaker, outlet

i need to test some outlets and im using a 25A 2P circuit breaker, from what i researched i need to connect neutral and hot to the circuit breaker and from there to the outlet. My question is, do I need to connect the ground wire directly to the outlet or is there another way? Thanks, Pedro.

Comment: What is the purpose of testing the outlets, and how does the circuit breaker come into it?  What do you expect to find from your tests?  By the way, in English "I" is always capitalized, and "I am" is often shortened to "I'm".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground wire should not be connected through the breaker, and directly to the ground.

Connecting it through the breaker would be a safety hazard.

Comment: Ok thanks Damien